# STM32F103 PLL comparing reset value with a flag value "CODE WISE"

Tags: stm32, stm32f1

I am trying to program an `STM32f10xx` `MCU` and trying to set the Clock. In the Reference manual It is written that the `PLL` when turned on, a flag will be set by the hardware indicating that it is ready or `LOCKED`, The flag bit is called `PLLRDY`. The `PLLRDY` is set by hardware to :

```
1 when the PLL is locked
0 when the PLL is not locked (NOT READY)
```

the CR register or Control Register's reset value is `ZERO` by default. and the `RCC_CR_PLLRDY =  0x02000000`

I need to put a while loop to check if the `PLL` is ready, is my implementation correct?

```c
  // Turn On PLL
  RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;

  // Wait while the PLL "Phase LOCKED LOOP" is Locked and stable:
  // Which is going to be set? the CR itself or the PLLRDY register?
  while( !(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) )
  {
    // Error when a certain time passes and the PLL is not ready!
  }
```

or should it be

```c
while( !(RCC->CR | RCC_CR_PLLRDY) )
{
  //SOME CODE!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`!(RCC->CR | RCC_CR_PLLRDY)` this will be always `false` as `RCC_CR_PLLRDY` is not zero and `non_zero | any_value` is always not zero.

To test if some bits are set you need to use `&` operator.

The first solution is OK

Comment: Ok but how is RCC_CR_PLLRDY not zero! the Reference manual states that this bit is set by hardware and the reset value of the register (of the RCC_CR_PLLRDY bit itself) is 0. Supposing that initially the RCC_CR_PLLRDY is zero then !( ZERO & ZERO) = ONE , and if the bit is set then !(ZERO & ONE) = ONE and this means that control will always be stuck in this while loop? am I missing something here?

Comment: `RCC_CR_PLLRDY` is a constant and it is not 0. So `RCC->CR | RCC_CR_PLLRDY` will always be non-zero  – independent of the value `RCC->CR` – and `!(RCC->CR | RCC_CR_PLLRDY)` will always evaluate to `false`. That's how bitwise OR works.

Comment: @The_M_Code I recommend you check the compiler settings. All current compilers can warn you about such programming errors.